# Can I update an object stored in two collections by changing it in just one?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, collections, nsdictionary

If I have something like this:

```
SomeObject *obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
obj.someIvar = 100;

NSMuteableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
[arr addObject:obj];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:50];
[dict setValue:obj forKey:@"key"];

[obj release];
```

Can I update obj like so:

```
SomeObject *objFromDict = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
objFromDict.someIvar = 5200;
```

...and expect the object in `arr` to be updated as well? I'm assuming collections are storing and giving out pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

In `NSMuteableArray *arr` and `NSMutableDictionary *dict` will be stored reference to object `SomeObject *obj`. When you are calling `[dict objectForKey:@"key"];` you get this reference and in expression `objFromDict.someIvar = 5200;` you are modifying `property` `someIvar`.

When you will try to get the same object from `arr` the value of `someIvar` will be also changed because of arrays and dictionaries just store references to instances.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for reaffirming that.